# Convert in R character formulas to numeric

Tags: r, special-characters, numeric

How can I convert y vector into a numeric vector.

y <- c("1+2", "0101", "5*5")

when I use

as.numeric(Y)

OUTPUT

Na 101 NA

Answer (score 4):

The following code

```
sapply(y, function(txt) eval(parse(text=txt)))
```

should to the work.

The problem is quite deep and you need to know about metaprogramming.
The problem with `as.numeric` is, that it only converts a string to a numeric, if the string only consists of numbers and one dot. Everything else is converted to `NA`. In your case, "1+2" contains a plus, hence NA. Or "5*5" contains a multiplication, hence NA. To say R that it should "perform the operation given by a string", you need `eval` and `parse`.

Comment: While unlikely to be a problem, realize that `eval(parse(...))` could allow inadvertent or malicious code injection. For instance, if `y <- c("1+1", "0101", "5*5", "q('no')")`, you're done. Again unlikely, but if you put this code near an uncontrolled user (e.g., shiny app, plumber interface, etc), then it's a non-zero possibility of significant problems. You might preempt it with some regexes to reduce the risk.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `map`

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(y, ~ eval(rlang::parse_expr(.x)))
#[1]   3 101  25
```